# Should I use "street" or "road" in this case?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Suppose that somebody asks me how to reach a place when I am at my cousin's. I don't live there, but I know the place enough to give indications. Suppose that I tell that person to follow the street he is on for half a mile, and then take another road in direction of a specific town.

I always used *street* to mean a public road in a city/town, but what should I use when I am not sure if the road is still in the town territory?

I imagine that if I say *street* and the person notices he is already outside the town, he would think he went too ahead, and missed the one I was talking of. If I say *road* when the road is still in the town territory, he could think he is supposed to go further ahead (and probably I was not precise when I said *half of a mile*).

Is there any way to avoid this kind of ambiguity, or isn't there any ambiguity at all?

Comment: kiam, I think "I always used" is not idiomatic English. As far as I know, with "always", and "never", you should say "I *have* always used". Please, if you verify this is a valid 'rule', give me a feedback, thank you!

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Not really – [have a look](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+always+used+the%2CI+always+used+the&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although most passages are named *streets* in town, and *roads* in between towns, it doesn't confuse people to call them otherwise. If I say to someone, "Take that road that goes from downtown Boston to the harbor," they won't think, "What does he mean? It must be a street!" Or if I say, "the street between Boston and New York," it will sound a little funny, but they will still know what I mean.

And certainly, there are streets within towns that are named Something-or-Other Road.

So using the word "road" or "street" is not really enough to tell someone whether they are in a town or outside a town, and whichever word you use is not enough to make them wonder whether you mean they are in a town or not. If *you* are wondering whether you are talking about being in a town or not, just say so to the person you are talking to.

Comment: John, so, if "the street between Boston and NY" sounds funny, but "take the road that goes from ..." doesn't sound so, it is because "road" is a hypernym of "street", perhaps?

Comment: I would agree. Moreover, in the context of giving directions, I'd say that _street_ and _road_ are pretty much interchangeable, at least in much of the U.S.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I would say you're right; "road" seems  superordinate to "street," although I agree with J.R. that they are somewhat interchangeable.